# Error CS0433 The type 'SpeechSynthesizer' exists in both 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract' and 'Windows'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, portable-class-library

I created a Portable Library project with Visual Studio 2015. I selected "Windows 10" as target but Visual Studio "downgrades" to Windows 8.1 automatically because "they support the same set of portable APIs"

My project has a reference to "Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract" because I use Speech Recognition but it seems to cause a conflict with Speech Synthesis libraries of Windows 8.1 which have the same name in Windows SDK and UniversalApiContract. The error is "Error CS0433 The type 'SpeechSynthesizer' exists in both 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract' and 'Windows'"

I'm stuck and I don't know what to do. ¿Is any way to force Visual Studio to use only the Windows 10 libraries? ¿Is it possible to rename the "SpeechSynthesizer" to make the compiler aware which library I want to use? ¿Is any better way to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I added an alias in the properties of the reference to "Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract"